# Как реализовать разграничение доступа к .php файлу?

Tags: php, .htaccess, права-доступа

Допустим есть index.php и private.php. Допустим, что в index.php есть форма, где пользователь вводит логин, пароль, потом проверяются его права. Если все ок, то его перенаправляет на site.com/private.php. Но что мешает злоумышленнику просто в адресной строке вбить site.con/private.php и пройти на данную страницу?

Какие есть способы предотвратить подобные уязвимости? Я слышал, что люди шаманят с .htaccess и редиректом, но я пока вот так сходу не могу придумать ничего путного. Заранее спасибо за подсказки

Comment: Создавать сессию пользователя после успешного ввода логина и пароля. На приватной странице проверять сессию

Comment: @ArchDemon а если страница не одна? На каждой сессию проверять? Разве это не уменьшит скорость работы? Или это единственный способ предотвратить доступ подобным способом?

Comment: На каждой странице, где нужно ограничить просмотр, нужно делать проверку. Если хотите потенциальное снижение скорости работы, то смотрите в сторону jwt. Там есть свои минусы и плюсы